# addClass active to bootstrap nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, in a bootstrap3 nav dropdown, etc..

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Here's My Fancy St. Patties Day link!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else entirely here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm highlighting the nav menu item via .active css with a simple jquery addClass to the parent element:

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

This then highlights the corresponding menu item when one is on said page.

My question is, how can I *also* add the class to the container '' (li > ul > li, etc..)? I've been stacking .parent() tags trying to get to it, no luck.

EDIT:

I thought something like this would add the active class to the container li class='dropdown':

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('li a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().eq(1).addClass('active');
```

..using .parent().eq(), but still nada!

Comment: On which element do you want to add active? on `a` or`li`?

Comment: `.parentsUntil()` should help you out if you're just adding `.active` to all elements regardless

Comment: Rather than chaining multiple `.parent()` methods, you should use the method `.closest()` - http://api.jquery.com/closest/ `$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').closest('.dropdown').addClass('active');`

Comment: On that container <li class='dropdown'>, the one containing the href.. thanks!

Comment: It it? <a href ="" class="active"? Check out my answer.

Comment: I already have the container li class='dropdown' getting the .active class, I *also* need the li container of *that* li to get the active class as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');//get the menu item
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li').last().addClass('active'); //get the parent
```

Thank you everyone.. traversing it with .eq(1) didn't seem to find it either.. I need to look into 'why'!

Answer (score 0):

Traverse to the closest .dropdown

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').closest('.dropdown').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector:

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').closest('.dropdown')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
```

This way remove class from other siblings also.